# Powershell Meta Data not returning results?

Tags: powershell, metadata

I am trying to get the dimensions of a picture in a directory and for some reason the code below is not returning back the value? $Picdata is empty? Any ideas..

```
$picdata = Get-FileMetaData -folder (Get-childitem ($SourceFolder + "\" + $Source.Name + "\Folder1") -Recurse -Directory).FullName
$picdata |Select 'Dimensions'
```

Comment: `Get-FileMetaData` is not a built-in command.  Where did you get this function/script?  We would likely need to see that source before being able to help.

Answer (score 1):

After I quick google search, it looks like you're referring to a post on "Hey, Scripting Guy":
http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2014/02/06/use-powershell-to-find-metadata-from-photograph-files.aspx

It looks like you may be trying to call the function without the full code.

The code is found here: 
http://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/get-file-meta-data-function-f9e8d804

I just tested the script on a folder and it seemed to work perfectly. Just change the path in the last line to point toward your folder.

```
Function Get-FileMetaData 
{ 

 Param([string[]]$folder) 
 foreach($sFolder in $folder) 
  { 
   $a = 0 
   $objShell = New-Object -ComObject Shell.Application 
   $objFolder = $objShell.namespace($sFolder) 

   foreach ($File in $objFolder.items()) 
    {  
     $FileMetaData = New-Object PSOBJECT 
      for ($a ; $a  -le 266; $a++) 
       {  
         if($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) 
           { 
             $hash += @{$($objFolder.getDetailsOf($objFolder.items, $a))  = 
                   $($objFolder.getDetailsOf($File, $a)) } 
            $FileMetaData | Add-Member $hash 
            $hash.clear()  
           } #end if 
       } #end for  
     $a=0 
     $FileMetaData 
    } #end foreach $file 
  } #end foreach $sfolder 
} #end Get-FileMetaData


$picdata = Get-FileMetaData -Folder 'C:\users\Public\Pictures' | select name, Dimensions
$picdata
```